# How can I use QTimer with QT' QMainWindow (QTimer works with QTWidget but not QMainWindow)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I have a QMainWindow created in QT Designer with a GraphicsView object that has been promoted to a pyQTGraph PlotWidget. I want to use a QTimer event to get live serial data (Y) and plot it with (X) being 1 second increments set by the QTimer event. However, the problem I'm having is that when using QT's QMainWindow as the main form I get the error "QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread", but if I use QT's QWidget as the main form everything works fine with no errors.

How can I use QTimer with QT's QMainWindow

QT4 and QT Designer
Python 3
PyQTGraph

Here is the Form Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'MainPlotWindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(735, 374)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.plot = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.plot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 681, 261))
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.plot.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.plot.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.plot.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.plot.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.plot.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plot.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plot"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 735, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))

from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
```

Here is the simple test program that reproduces the error:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, SIGNAL, QSettings
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg


from MainPlotWindow import *

'''=====================================================================
                            M A I N  G U I
   ====================================================================='''

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)



def PlotUpdate():
    print("Hello")



timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(PlotUpdate)
timer.start(1000) # 1 Second Refesh Rate



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you eyllanesc, that worked perfectly, thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that the `QTimer` this inside the widget, as I show in the following example:

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.PlotUpdate)
        timer.start(100) # 1 Second Refesh Rate
        self.curve = self.ui.plot.plot()
        self.counter = 0

    def PlotUpdate(self):
        x = self.counter + np.arange(0, 10)
        y = 10*np.sin(np.pi*x/10)
        self.curve.setData(x, y)
        self.counter += 1
```

Output:

[image]